# AppleScript + QuickTime — batch trim + create edit + export video

Tags: applescript, editing, quicktime

I'm looking for some help.

What I'm trying to do is to have AppleScript open a folder of videos, then get QuickTime to randomly trim them (as in the start frame from where it trims) and then have a variable length of the trim itself (say random between 1sec to 2sec as boundaries for the new 'clip'). After trimming and creating the new 'edit' (it would add this new random trimming to all the videos in the folder then add to timeline). QT then needs to export the edit to a new folder.

In summary, trying to make a quick auto-editing app that can just pick random selects from a folder full of videos then save an edit to a new video.

ANY help with this would be hugely appreciated!

I've been trying but to nail avail (I'm fairly new to coding to going around in circles).

Thanks!
Dylan

Comment: My advice would be to avoid trying to AppleScript _QuickTime_ as it's pretty buggy and a big headache.  Look at the command line tool `ffpmeg`, which can do that and so much more.  Being a command line tool also means you can use it from AppleScript, or from a bash script.

Comment: Not very clear at all. You start with a folder of videos, correct? What will the result be? A new video with random clips of random lengths selected in a random order from all the videos? What's the point of that? I suspect @CJK has the correct approach but the problem is unclear.

Comment: Hi, sorry — on second read, it was a bit convoluted. 

What I'm trying to do is essentially create a simple 'auto-editing' system. So you just load up a folder of videos, and then run a script that takes one small clip from each video in the folder and compiles them into a new clip / timeline (then exports to a final compiled video. To get interesting (and different each time) results, having some of the parameters random, for example,  the size of each clip could randomise between 1 and 3 seconds. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 3):

Like @CJK, I would recommend you use `bash` and `ffmpeg`  as they are both available on macOS and both better known and more widely applicable than Applescript and QuickTime.

IMHO, as Apple does not ship a package manager, you would be well advised to use **homebrew** to install, update and remove packages. It is available on the [homebrew website](https://brew.sh).

Once you have that, you can find any package you want with:

```
brew search packageXYZ
```

So, you can now install `ffmpeg` with:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Now you would want a `bash` script that:

- loops through all your ".mov" files in a directory
- gets their lengths
- calculates a random duration
- calculates a random start time
- extracts that piece of video as a clip
- and, finally at the end, assembles all the clips together

That will look something like this, which I would suggest you save in a `bash` script called `$HOME/RandomClips`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up globbing
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

# Clear list of files we are going to concatenate
> list.txt

N=1
# Loop through all ".MOV" files
for f in *.MOV ; do
   # Tell user which one we are processing
   echo Processing file $f

   # Get length of this video in seconds
   duration=$(mdls -raw -name kMDItemDurationSeconds "$f")
   echo ... Duration: $duration

   # Generate a random clip length less than 5 seconds
   ((seconds=RANDOM%5))
   echo ... Clip length: $seconds

   # Generate start time
   ((start=RANDOM%(duration-seconds)))
   echo ... Start time: $start

   # Extract clip into file called "Clip-1.mov", "Clip-2.mov" etc
   clipname="Clip-$N.mov"
   echo ... Extracting $clipname
   ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss $start -i "$f" -t $seconds -pix_fmt yuv420p "$clipname"

   # Add name of this clip to the list of files to concatenate at the end
   echo "file $clipname" >> list.txt

   # Increment clip counter
   ((N=N+1))
done

# Now join together all the extracted clips into a single file
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p mergedVideo.mov
```

Now you need to make that executable, just necessary once, with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/RandomClips
```

Then use `cd` to navigate to a directory of movies:

```
cd some/place/with/movies
```

and run the script with:

```
$HOME/RandomClips
```

The script is not the most robust or well-tested in the entire world but it should be 90+% good. You may have to resize videos to a fixed size so they all match formats. Likewise with codecs. Probably ask another question if that becomes an issue.

No-one said answers have to be 100% perfect, and as no-one else has suggested anything, this will hopefully get you well on your way.

---

If you want to debug the script, you can:

- read the debug output line by line
- check all the extracted clips look correct, i.e, "Clip-1.mov", "Clip-2.mov"
- read the file called "list.txt" to see if it contains all the clips